# MySQL: Handling high write rate + occasional reading to analytics table (Master/Slave)

Tags: mysql

We will be providing analytics, multiple writes will be made per seconds. Currently the databases are MariaDb. My aim is to be able to write as fast as I could to the database, and to be able to query the data occasionally on user request (through the web application). The read data doesn't have to be latest time. I could query analytics data and parse it every 5 minutes.

As I understand, if I set up a master/slave database relationship, I will be able to read from the slave database, and write as fast as I could to the master, while not locking the database. Is that right?

Are there any better ideas?

Comment: Your application will need to have the logic of reading from slave(s) only. If you have a single slave node then all writes will happen on slave too (coz of replication) and this node will have to serve the reads as well. In case of multiple slaves application will have to choose the slave node to read from as well.

Comment: Your proposed setup is fairly common. Long reads on the slave will not cause the master to slow down. The tradeoff is the slave may not always be perfectly up to date

Comment: Thank you... I have implemented it and will be researching performance.